# Trouble in using Matplotlib-cpp

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, anaconda

I encounter a problem on using the matplotlib-cpp in MacOS. Recently I download the matplotlibb-cpp into my macbook and try to run the sample code to see whether it works properly. I compile the sample code using

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++17 \
    -I /Users/pangkachun/matplotlib-cpp \
    -I /Users/pangkachun/miniforge3/include/python3.9 \
    -I /Users/pangkachun/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include \
    -L /Users/pangkachun/miniforge3/lib  \
    -lpython3.9 \
    -o plot
```

However, when I tried to execute the output file `./plot`, I got an error message from terminal

```
dyld[47656]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.9.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/pangkachun/plot
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpython3.9.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      ./plot
```

Could someone give me some guidelines on how to solve this problem?

""" Update"""

I use an alternative method to compile `./plot` which symlink the  `miniforge3/lib` that containing libpython3.9.dylib to `/usr/local/lib`. This `/usrlocal/lib` is created by my own under symlink. Although this works, I hope there is a "normal" method to deal with this issue.

Comment: Is the Conda environment activated when running?

Comment: @merv  Yes, I activate the coda base env while running